# Class not found exception in servlet and jdbc

Tags: java, database, servlets, jdbc

I am using servlet program with jdbc but when executing the program, getting `class not found` exception. I have included `ojdbc14.jar, servlet.api` in Eclipse (Junos) build path, but still getting the same exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at p1.dao.Goodsmain.custm(Goodsmain.java:26)
at p1.dao.Goodsmain.addgoods(Goodsmain.java:42)
at p1.goodsserv.doGet(goodsserv.java:54)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: but for normal jdbc connectivity it was executing..in case of servlet it throws exception.

Comment: put your jar into web-inf/lib folder

Comment: no errors with the code...problem with only the class not found exception

Comment: the jar files was already inside web inf/lib folder

Comment: jar should be within lib folder and lib folder within web-inf

Comment: what webserver are you using and what version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you make available the JDBC driver to your application.

Include the driver in the web-inf/lib folder of your application and it should work fine

Also note that this driver is  for use with JDK 1.4 and 1.5 according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

**UPDATE**
(if your server is running version other than 1.4 or 1.5 it will not work)

Comment: the ojdbc14.jar was inside javaresources/library how to switch it to web-inf/lib

Comment: @priya just copt-paste the `ojdbc14.jar` in your `web-inf/lib` folder in the directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

this first line of your **exception**

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl`

states that **drivers not found**

you should know that all the **external libraries** must be placed within `lib` of your `web-inf` folder  ie. `web-inf/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have seperate app server (tomcat) to load the webapp and encountering this exception. If this is the case, then ojdbc14.jar should be under WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp directory.

Please try to be specific about the exception and the app server you are using to get appropriate response.

Comment: the ojdbc14.jar was inside javaresources/library ow to switch it to web-inf/lib

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl

You should call:

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```